# Rebuilding timeseries index with 1 hour back

Tags: python, pandas, time, time-series

```
                     open  high   low  close  volume
2020-11-19 19:00:00  6.96  7.84  6.76   7.74   40061
2020-11-19 20:00:00  7.69  8.50  7.45   8.00   34025
2020-11-20 08:00:00  8.89 11.00  8.89   9.75   21143
2020-11-20 09:00:00  9.99 18.00  9.99  13.50   85387
2020-11-20 10:00:00 13.60 16.70 12.00  12.30  697481
2020-11-20 11:00:00 12.30 13.13 11.51  11.93  338253
2020-11-20 12:00:00 11.95 13.87 11.75  12.45  369936
2020-11-20 13:00:00 12.52 13.00 12.50  12.98  124967
2020-11-20 14:00:00 13.18 15.60 13.14  14.01  557167
2020-11-20 15:00:00 14.00 14.00 12.72  13.50  189481
2020-11-20 16:00:00 13.51 14.34 13.46  13.90  440768
2020-11-20 17:00:00 13.90 14.40 13.52  14.40   11724
2020-11-20 18:00:00 14.39 14.40 13.90  14.15    5474
2020-11-20 19:00:00 14.01 14.05 13.75  13.75    3794
2020-11-20 20:00:00 14.40 14.48 14.00  14.40    3152
```

I have a timeseries data like above, I want to remake index 1 hour back with the same o,h,l,c,v values. Like: 2020-11-20 20:00:00 will be -> 2020-11-20 19:00:00

I am converting my index to string with:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str)
```

Then tried below code. It is working if I only want to change 1 time but for the whole df, all times become 00:00:00 ???

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'00:00:00', '23:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'23:00:00', '22:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'22:00:00', '21:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'21:00:00', '20:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'20:00:00', '19:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'19:00:00', '18:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'18:00:00', '17:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'17:00:00', '16:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'16:00:00', '15:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'15:00:00', '14:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'14:00:00', '13:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'13:00:00', '12:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'12:00:00', '11:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'11:00:00', '10:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'10:00:00', '09:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'09:00:00', '08:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'08:00:00', '07:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'07:00:00', '06:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'06:00:00', '05:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'05:00:00', '04:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'04:00:00', '03:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'03:00:00', '02:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'02:00:00', '01:00:00', regex=True)
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'01:00:00', '00:00:00', regex=True)
```

Any ideas? or maybe a simple way to do this? FYI: Some hours are missing because of market closed times..

Comment: Why don't you simply minus a `Timedelta`, like `df.index = df.index - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = df.index - np.timedelta64(60,'m')
```